# Update customer password in WooCommerce admin orders dashboard

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

We have a pretty specific situation and I wonder anyone already make something similar. On Woocommerce order we generate user in WP with order mail. Then our agents need to change their password manually because this password is like a PIN code to their content. We ship these PIN numbers by classic mail in an envelope. The problem is that agents need to manually go from order dashboard to Users - find the right user and change their password. Is there any way to make an `input field` on the order dashboard to set a password for the user linked to this order?

Comment: Please check if any security implications with the below solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another similar way but this time on **Admin single edit order pages with a custom Metabox** on right side, using Ajax to update the customer password.

[image]

A message will be shortly displayed showing if this password update has succeeded or not disallowing empty password submissions or whitespaces in the password.

Here is the code:

```
// Adding a custom Metabox on WooCommerce single orders (on right side)
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_shop_order_metabox' );
function add_custom_shop_order_metabox(){
    global $post;

    $customer_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_customer_user', true );

    if ( $customer_id > 0 ) {
        add_meta_box(
            'custom_shop_order_metabox',
            __('Change password', 'woocommerce'),
            'content_custom_shop_order_metabox',
            'shop_order',
            'side',
            'core'
        );
    }
}

// Custom Metabox content on WooCommerce single orders
function content_custom_shop_order_metabox() {
    global $post;

    $customer_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_customer_user', true );

    echo '<div class="options_group edit_password" style="min-height:4.5em;margin-top:12px;;">
        <input type="text" name="customer-password" class="customer-password" value="">
        <a class="button submit-password" style="text-align:center;">' . __('Submit', 'woocommerce') . '</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="customer-id" class="customer-id" value="' . $customer_id . '">
        <div class="message-response" style="margin-top:6px;"></div>
    </div>';
}

// Jquery Ajax
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'edit_password_orders_column_js' );
function edit_password_orders_column_js() {
    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    if ( 'post.php' === $pagenow && 'shop_order' === $post_type ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('div.edit_password > .message-response').fadeOut(0);
        $('div.edit_password > .button.submit-password').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();

            var $this = $(this),
                $parent = $this.parent(),
                password = $parent.find('.customer-password').val(),
                user_id  = $parent.find('.customer-id').val(),
                text = '',
                color = 'red';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('/admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                data: {
                    'action'           : 'updating_customer_password',
                    'customer-password': password,
                    'customer-id'      : user_id
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if ( response === 'empty' ) {
                        text  = '<?php echo __('Empty input, retry…', 'woocommerce'); ?>';
                    } else if ( response === 'whitespace' ) {
                        text  = '<?php echo __('No white spaces…', 'woocommerce'); ?>';
                    } else {
                        text  = '<?php echo __('Password Updated!', 'woocommerce'); ?>';
                        color = 'green';
                    }
                    $parent.find('.customer-password').val('');
                    $parent.find('.message-response').html('<small>'+text+'<small>').css('color',color).fadeIn();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $parent.find('.message-response').fadeOut( function(){ $(this).css('color','black').html(''); });
                    }, 2000)
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// PHP Ajax receiver
add_action('wp_ajax_updating_customer_password', 'action_ajax_updating_customer_password');
function action_ajax_updating_customer_password() {
    if ( isset($_POST['customer-password']) && isset($_POST['customer-id']) ) {
        $password = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customer-password'] );
        $user_id  = intval( esc_attr( $_POST['customer-id'] ) );

        if ( ! $password ) {
            echo 'empty'; // empty input
        } elseif ( strpos($password, ' ') !== false ) {
            echo 'whitespace'; // empty input
        } else {
            wp_set_password( $password, $user_id ); // Set new password
        }
        wp_die();
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a complete solution that will add in admin orders list a custom column with a button (in each row) allowing editing the user password via Ajax.

[image]

Then when shop manager will click on the button of the desired order, an input text field will appear where the new password can be updated via Ajax.

[image]

A message will be shortly displayed showing if this update has succeeded or not.

So here is the complete code:

```
// Add a column to admin orders list
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_edit_password_orders_column' );
function add_edit_password_orders_column( $columns ) {
    if( current_user_can( 'edit_shop_orders' ) ) {
        $sorted_columns = [];

        foreach ( $columns as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $key === 'order_total') {
                $sorted_columns[ 'edit_password' ] = __('Edit password', 'woocommerce');
            }
            $sorted_columns[$key] = $columns[$key];
        }

        return $sorted_columns;
    }
    return $columns;
}

// Column content
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'edit_password_orders_column_row_content' );
function edit_password_orders_column_row_content( $column ) {
    if ( 'edit_password' === $column ) {
        global $post, $the_order;

        $user = $the_order->get_user();

        if( is_a($user, 'WP_User') && $user->ID > 0 ) {
            echo '<div class="edit_password userid-' . $user->ID . '" data-user_id="' . $user->ID . '">
                <a class="button user-login" style="text-align:center; display:block;">' . __('Edit', 'woocommerce') . '</a>
                <div  class="hidden-fields" style="display:none;">
                    <input type="text" name="customer-password" class="customer-password" value="" style="width:auto; max-width:120px; margin-bottom: 6px;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="customer-id" class="customer-id" value="' . $user->ID . '">
                    <a class="button submit-password" style="text-align:center;">' . __('Ok', 'woocommerce') . '</a>
                </div>
                <div class="message-response" style="display:none;">Message</div>
            </div>';
        } else {
            echo __("Guest user", "woocommerce");
        }
    }
}

// Jquery Ajax
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'edit_password_orders_column_js' );
function edit_password_orders_column_js() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( $pagenow === 'edit.php' && isset($_GET['post_type']) && 'shop_order' === $_GET['post_type'] ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('div.edit_password > .button.user-login').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).hide('fast');
            $(this).parent().find('.hidden-fields').show('slow');
        });

        $(document.body).on('click focus focusin', 'div.edit_password input.customer-password', function(e){
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });

        $('div.edit_password .button.submit-password').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();

            var $this = $(this),
                $parent = $this.parent(),
                password = $parent.find('input.customer-password').val(),
                user_id  = $parent.find('input.customer-id').val(),
                text = '',
                color = 'red';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('/admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                data: {
                    'action'           : 'updating_customer_password',
                    'customer-password': password,
                    'customer-id'      : user_id
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if ( response === 'empty' ) {
                        text  = '<?php echo __('Empty input, retry…', 'woocommerce'); ?>';
                    } else if ( response === 'whitespace' ) {
                        text  = '<?php echo __('No white spaces…', 'woocommerce'); ?>';
                    } else {
                        text  = '<?php echo __('Updating password!', 'woocommerce'); ?>';
                        color = 'green';
                    }
                    $parent.find('input.customer-password').val('');
                    $parent.parent().find('.hidden-fields').hide('fast');
                    $parent.parent().find('div.message-response').css('color',color).html('<small>'+text+'<small>').show();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $parent.parent().find('div.message-response').css('color','black').html('').hide();
                        $parent.parent().find('a.user-login').show();
                    }, 2000);

                    console.log(response); // For testing (to be removed)
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    $this.parent().parent().find('.hidden-fields').hide('fast');
                    $this.parent().parent().find('div.message-response').html('Error!').css('color',color).show();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $parent.parent().find('div.message-response').css('color','black').html('').hide();
                        $parent.parent().find('a.user-login').show();
                    }, 2000);

                    console.log(error); // For testing (to be removed)
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// PHP Ajax receiver
add_action('wp_ajax_updating_customer_password', 'action_ajax_updating_customer_password');
function action_ajax_updating_customer_password() {
    if ( isset($_POST['customer-password']) && isset($_POST['customer-id']) ) {
        $password = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['customer-password'] );
        $user_id  = intval( esc_attr( $_POST['customer-id'] ) );

        if ( ! $password ) {
            echo 'empty'; // empty input
        } elseif ( strpos($password, ' ') !== false ) {
            echo 'whitespace'; // empty input
        } else {

            wp_set_password( $password, $user_id ); // Set new password
        }
        wp_die();
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I just tried this. Logged in as admin, clicking the edit button on a order made by the logged in admin account, the "error" message `No input or guest user` is shown. Not sure if that's by design or not - but the password is changed and shortly after - I am asked to login again by the modal login that appears.

Comment: It is also possible to leave it blank and / or just press the spacebar a few times. if doing so, you cannot login again and you have to reset the pw using phpmyadmin.

Overall though, a few nice feature :)

Comment: @HaroldAldersen I have updated the code… A red notice will be displayed if the password is empty or has white spaces avoiding password update. A green notice will be displayed when the password is saved… It's normal that a modal login that appears shortly after updating a password for the current user, as user session is reseted by wordpress.

Comment: Amazing solution! I just wonder, is possible to put this password box on the next step, when the order details are opened?

Answer (score 4):

This will help you to add a new column in the order list table - that contains the link to edit user of the corresponding customer.

```
function wc_new_order_column( $columns ) {
    $columns[ 'customer' ] = 'Customer';
    return $columns;
}

add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'wc_new_order_column' );

function add_order_name_column_content( $column ) {
    global $post;

    if ( 'customer' === $column ) {

        $order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
        $link = get_edit_user_link($order->get_customer_id());
        $name = $order->get_billing_first_name();

        echo "<a target='_blank' href=".$link.">".$name."</a>";
    }
}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'add_order_name_column_content' );
```

Comment: It's pretty nice hack, but do you think it's possible to add password box in next steps (opened order dashboard)? So there is no redirects between two pages?